# How can I cancel a long-running query using Spring and JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

The JDBC `java.sql.Statement` class has a `cancel()` method. This can be called in another thread to cancel a currently running statement.

How can I achieve this using Spring? I can't find a way to get a reference to a statement when running a query. Nor can I find a cancel-like method.

Here's some sample code. Imagine this takes up to 10 seconds to execute, and sometimes on the user's request, I want to cancel it:

```
    final int i = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select max(gameid) from game");
```

How would I modify this so I have a reference to a `java.sql.Statement` object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me simplify oxbow_lakes's answer: you can use the `PreparedStatementCreator` variant of the query method to gain access to the statement.

So your code:

```
final int i = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select max(gameid) from game");
```

Should turn into:

```
final PreparedStatement[] stmt = new PreparedStatement[1];
final int i = (Integer)getJdbcTemplate().query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        stmt[0] = connection.prepareStatement("select max(gameid) from game");
        return stmt[0];
    }
}, new ResultSetExtractor() {
    public Object extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        return resultSet.getString(1);
    }
});
```

Now to cancel you can just call

```
stmt[0].cancel()
```

You probably want to give a reference to `stmt` to some other thread before actually running the query, or simply store it as a member variable. Otherwise, you can't really cancel anything...

Answer (score 2):

You can execute stuff via `JdbcTemplate` methods which allow you to pass in a `PreparedStatementCreator`. You could always use this to intercept invocations (perhaps using a `Proxy`) which caused a `cancel` to happen on a separate thread by some `cond` became `true`.

```
public Results respondToUseRequest(Request req) {
    final AtomicBoolean cond = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    requestRegister.put(req, cond);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
             public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection conn) {
               PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement();
               return proxyPreparedStatement(stmt, cond);
             }
         }, 
         new ResultSetExtractor() { ... });
}
```

This `canceller` could itself be cancelled upon successful completion; for example

```
private final static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                 Executors.newSingleThreadedScheduledExecutor();  

PreparedStatement proxyPreparedStatement(final PreparedStatement s, AtomicBoolean cond) {
    //InvocationHandler delegates invocations to the underlying statement
    //but intercepts a query 
    InvocationHandler h = new InvocationHandler() {

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) {
            if (m.getName().equals("executeQuery") {
                Runnable cancel = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { 
                        try {
                            synchronized (cond) {
                                while (!cond.get()) cond.wait();
                                s.cancel(); 
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                    } 
                }
                Future<?> f = scheduler.submit(cancel);
                try {
                    return m.invoke(s, args);
                } finally {
                    //cancel the canceller upon succesful completion
                    if (!f.isDone()) f.cancel(true); //will cause interrupt
                }
            }
            else {
                return m.invoke(s, args);
            }   
        }

    }

    return (PreparedStatement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                getClass().getClassLoader(), 
                new Class[]{PreparedStatement.class}, 
                h);
```

So now the code that is responding to a user's cancellation would look like:

```
cond.set(true);
synchronized (cond) { cond.notifyAll(); }
```

Comment: An interesting and odd example, not entirely sure how that could be applied to the problem at hand. Obviously that 10 second auto-cancel would need replacing with something externally triggered.

Comment: Why would it have to be externally triggered? The OP didn't mention anything about it being,say, user-defined

Comment: OP here: actually, I do want the cancel to be triggered in response to user action.

Comment: Then this is also pretty easy with my method. Instead of a canceller action which just sleeps you can run up some kind of listener which wakes up the canceller when done. I've modified my answer

Comment: The modifications I've made are just a proof-of-concept; obviously you wouldn't want to cause your thread-pool threads to wait in reality - you'd add some kind of UserTriggerListener

Comment: This code seems to assume I already have a reference to the statement. The problem I have is not how to cancel once I have the reference to a statement. The problem is how to get the statement. This is what I can't figure out.

Comment: But I've said that in the first line of my answer: use the mechanism Spring provides for you to use a PreparedStatementCreator. You'll get given a Connection and you will want to create this statement proxy (above) delegating to a PS that you create yourself from the Connection parameter.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to register somewhere the cond variable with the user request so that you can then later wakeup the waiting cancel

Comment: I've modified my answer again

Answer (score 1):

You can register a callback object of type `StatementCallback` on `JdbcTemplate` that will get executed with the currently active statement as a parameter. In this callback you can then cancel the statement:

```
simpleJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(new StatementCallback() {

    @Override
    public Object doInStatement(final Statement statement) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        if (!statement.isClosed()) {
            statement.cancel();
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by Spring you mean the use of JdbcDaoTemplate and/or JdbcTemplate? If so, this doesn't really help or hinder you in solving your problem.

I'll assume your use case is that you're executing a DAO operation in one thread, and another thread comes in and wants to cancel the first thread's operation.

The first problem you have to solve is, how does the second thread know which one to cancel? Is this a GUI with a fixed number of threads, or a server with several?

Once you've solved that part, you need to figure out how to cancel the statement in the first thread. One simple approach to this would be to store the first thread's PreparedStatement in a field somewhere (perhaps in a simple field, perhaps in a map of thread ID to statements), allowing the second thread to come in, retrieve the statwmentand call cancel() on it.

Bear in mind that it's possible that cancel() may just block, depending on your JDBC driver and database. Also, make sure you think hard about synchronization here, are your threads are going to get into a fight.

Comment: That's great and detailed info, but the question I looking to be answered is this: How can I get a reference to a statement when running a query via JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Well you should have said so :) As @oxbow said, you can use a custom instance of PreparedStatementCreator to get control over statement creation, and then pass that to the JdbcTemplate.