# Stop executing Spring JDBC query programmatically in Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Currently, I'm running long running MySQL queries using Java Spring JDBC library. For this program, I want a way of stopping a running query. I want to do this programmatically, so killing processes is not what I need here.

Also, setting timeouts and killing threads using Java code is not preferred.

Is there a way to do this using programming conventions, or is there any preferred way or design to achieve this use case in Java?

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28481809/4808122), but you should always test the `stmt.cancel()` with your database and your driver and your use case if it realy works...

Comment: I'm using Spring JDBC, we have an option to cancel statement there? I can't find it.

Comment: If you use `jdbctemplate` you should tag the question accordingly. `cancel` is a *plain* JDBC function with which you tagged your question. But it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054642/4808122) you can use it as well in your context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel SQL Statement with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481809/cancel-sql-statement-with-jdbc)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I have updated my question, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL KILL Command to stop a process

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                    | Info              | Progress |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
|  1 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  2 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  3 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  4 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  5 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL              |    0.000 |
| 46 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |   56 | User sleep               | select sleep(199) |    0.000 |
| 47 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init                     | show processlist  |    0.000 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> kill 46;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                    | Info             | Progress |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
|  1 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|  2 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|  3 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|  4 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL             |    0.000 |
|  5 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 47 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init                     | show processlist |    0.000 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but i want to do this using Java